# RX + TPL + Testing

Tags: c#, testing, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

I currently struggling with the issue testing a `TPL` function inside of a `RX statement. The problem is also that I don't have access to the observable.

Here is my test:

```
[Test]
public void TestRaceConditions()
{
    // Arrange
    TestScheduler testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
    List<string> source = new List<string> {"Hello"};
    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    source.ToObservable().SelectMany(v => Task.Run(() => 
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000); // Simulate long running operation
        return v;
    }).ToObservable(testScheduler))
    .ObserveOn(testScheduler)
    .Subscribe(s => results.Add(s));

    // Act
    testScheduler.Start();

    Assert.That(results.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
    Assert.That(results[0], Is.EqualTo("Hello"));
}
```

I've googled around and found many articles and advices like:

- Do not mix `TPL` and `RX`
- Create a wrapper for the `TPL` code where you can mock and return a completed task. ==> But what about integration tests?

What I also tried is to create a custom `TaskScheduler`, but then I have to replace every `Task.Run` with `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

So the question is:

- How to get control over the task or the observable in the test just with `Schedulers` that I know when all elements are processed and finished?

**UPDATE: Real Example**

```
public class ResultController : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IServiceClient _serviceClient;
    private readonly IDisposable _subscription;

    public ResultController(IEventProvider eventProvider, 
                            IServiceClient serviceClient, 
                            ISchedulerProvider schedulerProvider)
    {
        _serviceClient = serviceClient;
        _subscription = eventProvider.Events.SelectMany(e => LoadDataAsync(e.Id))
                                            .SubscribeOn(schedulerProvider.TaskPool)
                                            .ObserveOn(schedulerProvider.Dispatcher)
                                            .Subscribe(OnNewDataLoaded);
    }

    private void OnNewDataLoaded(Data data)
    {

    }

    public async Task<Data> LoadDataAsync(int id)
    {
        ////return Task.Run(() =>
        ////{
        ////    Thread.Sleep(10000);
        ////    return new Data();
        ////});

        return await _serviceClient.LoadDataByIdAsync(id);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _subscription.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This solution works in production without problems, but in testing I do not have the task under control.

- Mocking the `ServiceClient` and returning a completed `Task` works fine.
- But in IntegrationTests with SpecFlow, I don't know when the work is finished without introducing hacking properties for synchronization.

Comment: The answer is not to mix Rx and TPL. Just use Rx. Why do you need TPL?

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks :-) Yes I know, but if you have a lot of code which already use tasks to load some data from the server. It's not possible to remove that. In the production code is also not a case.

Comment: Can you show the actual code rather than an artificial example?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what's going on here is that you assert the results of the work before they are done:

```
// starts a work in a different thread
// and continues the test right after firing work up
testScheduler.Start();

// results here are empty for a 10 seconds
Assert.That(results.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
Assert.That(results[0], Is.EqualTo("Hello"));
```

What you can do here is subscribe to a continuation of task you're scheduling by [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run.aspx), you can also introduce an array of tasks and add that task to it and wait for them, and only after that do your checks.

Introducing a custom scheduler might not be helpful because of your simulating work - you still have to wait for 10 seconds for a thread to wake up. Maybe another option is to use [`Task.Delay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay.aspx) method instead, which can be ignored by your test scheduler.

Comment: Yeah, but then I need to expose ugly sychronization properties.

I also don't want to Task.Delay neither Thread.Sleep. It was just for demonstation. I already added a more real scenario.

Comment: Then you may add some waiting inside your tests

Comment: Which will introduce flaky tests and this is the root cause why I'm asking this. :-)

Comment: Then yeah, some `Decorator` class for tasks, which creates already completed tasks in case of integration tests .